# how to use org.kohsuke.github library to get details about a given commit

Tags: java, github, github-api

It is possible to get details about a certain commit by providing its commit hash to the `github REST api V3` found in here [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-commits) How do I obtain the same from `org.kohsuke.github java api` found in this [link](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/)? I have written following program, but have no idea how to continue the code for getting what I need. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
public void apiCallerFromGithubLibrary() {

        try {
            GitHub gitHub = GitHub.connectUsingPassword("username", "password");
            System.out.println(gitHub.isCredentialValid());

            //search content
            GHContentSearchBuilder ghContentSearchBuilder = gitHub.searchContent();
            ghContentSearchBuilder.q("hash%3A380b33f74893e15c8db8b86b6b53682a64928695");



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-commits/#search-by-hash), the syntax for the search query uses a `:` not a `%`, so like:

```
searchBuilder.q("hash:124a9a0ee1d8f1e15e833aff432fbb3b02632105");
```

Aside from that it looks like you are on the way.

There are some examples in [the Unit Tests for the library you are using](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/blob/master/src/test/java/org/kohsuke/github/AppTest.java) of how searches work.

I think you want to do something like:

```
PagedSearchIterable<GHContent> iterableContent =
    gitHub.searchContent()
        .q("hash:124a9a0ee1d8f1e15e833aff432fbb3b02632105")
        .list();

// Iterate over content
GHContent content = iterableContent.iterator().next(); // etc..
```

The `GHContentSearchBuilder` you are using directly is actually the type that is returned when you call the friendlier `searchContent()` method, on the top level API of the `GitHub` class.

Note that I've never used this library before, so there may be some gaps to fill in. But hopefully that will get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let you know the results